# std::vector<unsigned short> somehow contains numbers > 300?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<unsigned short>` that somehow contains numbers that are greater than 300.

`unsigned short` usually only permits 0 to 255, nowhere in the program attempts to add numbers that large and presumably attempts should fail.

How might this have occurred?

edit: Sorry about this, it's not much of a useful question, seems I had the `usigned short` range wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `unsigned short` usually only permits 0 to 255

This is incorrect; `unsigned short` must have a range at least 0 to 65,535 (2<sup>16</sup> - 1).

Comment: oh, yeah. Just looked it up. I've been using them for small (8bit) numbers for ages, can't believe I've never noticed, guess it would never cause a problem that there was more storege than I required.

Comment: I'm going to mark you'r answer as correct but might vote to delete the question as well :¬P

Comment: Just give the guy the +15 reputation and accept his answer! :D (Maybe then delete the question)